# How to runtime make a multidimensional array from a string.

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having a generic string $a and exploding it for dot es:

```
$b = explode(".", $a)
```

How i can to Runtime code it dinamically without to know `count($b)` value:

```
if (count($b) == 1) {
    $c[$b[0]] = $var;
} elseif (count($b) == 2) {
    $c[$b[0]][$b[1]] = $var;
} elseif (count($b) == 3) {
    $c[$b[0]][$b[1]][$b[2]] = $var;
} ... {
    ...
} elseif (count($b) == n-1) {
    $c[$b[0]][$b[1]][$b[2]]...[$b[n-2]] = $var;
} elseif (count($b) == n) {
     $c[$b[0]][$b[1]][$b[2]]...[$b[n-1]] = $var;
} else {
     $c = $var;
}
```

It is a pseudocode ofcourse for give an idea about what i mean.

Comment: Could you please add an example string and the expected output? And have you actually tried anything yourself, or are you asking us to do all the work for you?

Comment: Can you post `$a` string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution **without** `eval()` and recursion:

```
function split_to_multi($string, $value)
{
    $levels = explode('.', $string);
    $result = [];
    foreach (array_reverse($levels) as $key) {
        $result = [$key => $value];
        $value = $result;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

For example:

```
print_r(split_to_multi('foo.bar.baz', 123));
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [baz] => 123
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions:

### Recursive function

The first is using a recursive function that will add each new element on the array.

### Evaluation method

Another method, very quick ... but it's using an **evaluation** function. I'm not a big fan of such. Use it when you know all sides effect on your script.

[php convert flat family list to tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200756/php-convert-flat-family-list-to-tree/41201209#41201209)

```
function arrayToTree_eval(array $source, $defaultValue = null) {

    eval(sprintf('$tree%s = $defaultValue;', '["' . implode('"]["', $values) . '"]'));
    // will create a $tree['a']['b']['...'] = $defaultValue

    return $tree;
}

var_dump( arrayToTree_eval( explode('.', 'a.b.c.d') ) );
```